# Ender V3 SE middle of print bed sticking but fine elsewhere

Tags: creality-ender-3, adhesion

Recently got an Ender V3 SE and new to 3D printing. I am having issues where the prints are sticking hard to the middle of the print bed and are difficult to remove, often with damage to the bottom. If offset anywhere else on the bed, the prints are fine. Wondering if the build plate has an issue

Answer (score 0):

Consider to measure the nozzle distance from the bed at the "normal" points, those at which you have no release problems and compare that distance to the points at which the release is difficult. It's not out of the realm of possibility that your bed has a substantial enough distortion to cause the nozzle to too-heavily bond the filament to the bed.

If you're willing to put a bit more effort into the solution, you can install Octoprint on just about anything and run the [Bed Level Visualizer](https://3dprintscape.com/octoprint-bed-level-visualizer-complete-setup-guide/) which will present a color graph representing the flatness of the bed. Image below from linked site:

[image: bed level visualizer graph]

It's important when running this program to note the scale for the axes. The linked image shows rather large scale which presents a fairly distorted bed, but I've seen similar images in which the scale was one-tenth or one one-hundredth of this image. As a result the distortion is relatively severe, but absolutely measured, quite insignificant.